# Path in Prolog with open and consult

Tags: prolog

I use `consult` with path of file that i would load. For example:

```
consult('C:/path1/path2/myfile.pl).
```

And i use this method also for `open`:

```
open('C:/path1/path2/path3/fileopen.pl', write, Stream).
```

Is there a method for indicate only the name of file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If myfile.pl is located in your working directory, simply `consult(myfile)` will work.

SWI-Prolog allows the definition of symbolic search paths, by means of [file_search_path](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=file_search_path/2).
For instance, when I wanted to try parts of a published open source Prolog project ([blipkit](http://www.blipkit.org/)), all I had to do, after dowloading the source, was adding to my preference file

```
user:file_search_path(blipkit, '/home/carlo/prolog/blipkit-master/packages').
user:file_search_path(bio, blipkit(blipcore)).
user:file_search_path(bio, blipkit(sql)).
```

Anyway, factorizing the common parts is always, in any language, the right way to do.

```
get_path(File, Path) :- format(atom(Path), 'C:/path1/path2/path3/~s.pl', [File]).
```